# How to add a JAAS login module to Artemis?

Tags: java, authentication, jaas, activemq-artemis

I'd like to add a custom JAAS login module to ActiveMQ Artemis. Therefore, I created a class (i.e. `MyLogin`) that implements `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`.

```java
public class MyLogin implements javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule
{

    @Override
    public boolean abort() throws LoginException
    {
        out( "abort" );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException
    {
        out( "commit" );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize( Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options )
    {
        out( "initialize" );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException
    {
        out( "login" );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean logout() throws LoginException
    {
        out( "logout" );
        return true;
    }

    private void out( String msg )
    {
        System.out.println( "MSO: " + msg );
        System.err.println( "MSW: " + msg );

    }

}
```

I put this class in a jar and put it into the `%artemis_home%/lib` directory.

In `login.config` I changed the entry for `activemq` to

```
activemq {
    t1.security.MyLogin sufficient
    debug=true
};
```

What I'd expect is that each connection will succeed, but it simply does not work. Now all connections are refused, and I don't see any of the messages printed out in `MyLogin` class.

Is there any way to find out if this `LoginModule` is loaded, or how can I debug this?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't seeing any logging then the login module isn't being loaded. I think the culprit may be a syntax error in your `login.config`. You're missing a semicolon (i.e. `;`) after `debug=true`. You should be using this:

```
activemq {
    t1.security.MyLogin sufficient
    debug=true;
};
```

Also, you can turn on `DEBUG` logging for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager` to potentially get more information about what's happening.